# NetSuite Advanced PDF Templates PDF/A Compliant

Tags: netsuite, bfo

Looking for some assistance if anyone out there knows how (if it's possible) NetSuite's Advanced PDF can generate PDF/A compliant documents.

Most of our PDFs do not require compliance, however a handful of template do require it

I did find a reference to some meta tags, but continually get Unexpected SuiteScript Error. I downloaded Adobe's ICC profiles. Below links to "Color Match sRGB" icc profile stored in the file cabint (available without login)

The "test" template has no named fonts or transparent images.

```
<meta name="output-profile" value="PDF/A1b:2005"/>
<meta name="output-intent-icc" value="https://XXXXXXXXXXX.app.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=21283340&amp;c=4203910&amp;h=bMlY3nvM0WHZpRjt72bV2tvYUe9qW8loEWQ5TfLxcOmcKj1e&amp;_xt=.bin"/>
<meta name="output-intent-identifier=" value="sRGB"/>
```